# Nested List how go step by step based on what button was clicked

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two buttons Yes and No. Based on the button chosen I need to go through my nested lists of: if yes - Right; if no - Left. Example:

```
nodes.ElementAt(0).Left.ElementAt(0).Right.ElementAt(0).Name.ToString()
```

User clicked No and Yes

But I can't write so statically because the user can click many times on the button. How do I write it more efficiently?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Yes - button 
        nodes.ElementAt(0).Right.ElementAt(0).Name.ToString();

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //No - button
        nodes.ElementAt(0).Left.ElementAt(0).Name.ToString();

        // If user clicked again no button i need to see where i was before in that list
        // example if user was clicked before yes - button than 
        nodes.ElementAt(0).Left.ElementAt(0).Right.ElementAt(0).Left.Name.ToString();



    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? , give us more explanation.

Comment: I uptaded, look what i want achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply store use a pointer to the current node in a seperate variable.
Initialize your current node after you built your tree.

```
currentNode = nodes.ElementAt(0); // initialize
```

Then handle your buttons (and you might add some null checking)

```
if(noClicked && currentNode.Left != null) {
  currentNode = currentNode.Left.ElementAt(0);
} else if(yesClicked && currentNode.Right != null) {
  currentNode = currentNode.Right.ElementAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Okey i'm working on that now

Comment: Thank you, yes this is works for me as i wanted!

Comment: actually its really simple task, but i dont know how i can stucked on this... but thank you!

Comment: Happens to everyone sometimes. You're welcome